# AVERAGEIF error with arbitrary list of values passed for range parameter

Tags: excel, average

I have an average returning expression:

```
=AVERAGE((C6*D6);(E6*F6);(G6*H6);(I6*J6);(K6*L6);(M6*N6);(O6*P6);(Q6*R6);(S6*T6);(U6*V6))
```

Since it returns wrong values if any of the elements is zero, I wish to exclude zeros from calculation, by replacing **`AVERAGE`** with **`AVERAGEIF`** function:

```
=AVERAGEIF(((C6*D6);(E6*F6);(G6*H6);(I6*J6);(K6*L6);(M6*N6);(O6*P6);(Q6*R6);(S6*T6);(U6*V6));"<>0")
```

However, Excel does not accept this formula. What is wrong with the formula?

I have also tried with the solution suggested here for non-contigous ranges: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/conditional-average-on-non-contiguous-ranges-using-frequency/ but with no success.

```
=SUM(C6*D6;E6*F6;G6*H6;I6*J6;K6*L6;M6*N6;O6*P6;Q6*R6;S6*T6;U6*V6)/INDEX(FREQUENCY((C6*D6;E6*F6;G6*H6;I6*J6;K6*L6;M6*N6;O6*P6;Q6*R6;S6*T6;U6*V6);0);2)
```

I get #VALUE! error.

Comment: `AVERAGEIF` doesn't accept an arbitrary list of values like `AVERAGE` does, but only a range of cells. Can you store your intermediate results first?

Comment: The whole `SUM`/`INDEX`/`FREQUENCY` cleverness will not work, for the same reason -- you're trying to apply these formulas to values rather than cell ranges, which they don't support. Although it is possible to supply one single formula that will work (by simply enumerating all the possible cases of pairs being zero with `IF`) and `COUNT`ing those, it won't be pretty.

Comment: Put this as the bottom part of your last formula: `=SUMPRODUCT((C6*D6>0)*(E6*F6>0)*(G6*H6>0)*(I6*J6>0)*(K6*L6>0)*(M6*N6>0)*(O6*P6>0)*(Q6*R6>0)*(S6*T6>0)*(U6*V6>0))`